# How Do I Install Drivers For GeForce 8800 GTS 512?

Tags: nvidia

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 32 bit with integrated video card

I would like to disable the integrated video card and make the GeForce 8800 GTS 512 as the main one when booting up. Please help me with the driver installation.

description: VGA compatible controller

product: G92 [GeForce 8800 GTS 512]

vendor: NVIDIA Corporation

physical id: 0

bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0

version: a2

width: 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

To install nVIDIA Display Driver release 270.41.19 in Ubuntu 11.04 Natty or 11.10 Oneiric, open Terminal and run:

Code:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update           
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

After the installation restart the system to enable the driver.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the suitable Nvidia driver from [here](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/304.64/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.64.run)
2. Install the driver manually [This link will help you](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-304.108-driver)
3. To install it manually

First press ctrl + alt +f1 This will open tty1

Now you are using the tty terminal console

log in with your user name and password

Now stop the lightdm(dgm or whatever) using the command

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

Then install the new driver with

```
sudo sh /path-to-the-driver
```

- if something goes wrong close the installer and reboot then try again
- still same problem the nvidia installer will make a black list in /etc/modprobe.d/
- if this is not generated you have to make such file to black list nouveau
- Run sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf and fill it with this:
  blacklist nouveau
- If the problem is not solve you have to add the string "nomodeset" to your /etc/default/grub, in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= line
- then update the grub

  `sudo update-grub`