# Looking to upgrade my graphic card

Tags: nvidia, graphics

So I'm like super new to Ubuntu and I've never actually upgraded my graphic card on anything before. That being said I'm thinking of getting the Nvidia GeForce 8800 GT because I found it cheap. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on an old HP Compaq 6910p. Would I run into any problems with nVidia and will Ubuntu support it right away, or will I have to grab the drivers before I upgrade it?

Lastly, if anyone knows of a better graphic card for this laptop for around $50 I'm all ears, I'm still poking around before I buy.

Comment: The Compaq 6910p has a built on ATI Mobility Radeon X2300 that is not upgradeable.  The NVIDIA 8800 GT is designed for desktop / tower systems.  But according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver it is fully supported.

Comment: @Terrance - How is the ATI page relevant here ? The nvidia card is not listed. The 8800 GT has had problems in the past, I would advise it with caution.

Comment: Check linux compatibility lists - http://askubuntu.com/questions/269383/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-geforce-8800-gts-512

Comment: @bodhi.zazen The Compaq 6910 is a laptop without an upgradeable card.  You CANNOT ADD the GeForce 8800GT to that system.  Please read the hardware specs before you comment.  http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04142126

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Plus, I was commenting that the ATI Mobility Radeon X2300 is fully supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to upgrade the graphic card of a laptop, unless you find a motherboard with the graphic card you need that fits the case.

This may happen only between products of the same vendor and of the same product line, because usually laptops motherboard are custom built for the specific product / product line. So you should look at motherboards (not graphic cards) of the same line of the HP Compaq 6910p.

That being said, it might be very easy to upgrade a desktop's graphic card, while the same is not true for laptops.

Laptops are not meant to be assembled / disassembled, and the internal parts (beside the HDD and the memory, and expecially the motherboard) are usually unaccessible prior to a complete disassembly of the laptop. So beware.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking and why I wanted to ask before purchasing. Thanks!